# In Java Swing is there a way to set the cursor in the title bar of a JFrame instance?

Tags: java, swing

I have been tasked with allowing the user to change the mouse cursor image in a large Swing application with many independent JFrame, JDialog, etc. instances.

I was able to get pretty close to what I wanted by using the Component method

`public void setCursor(Cursor cursor)`

I can use this to set the cursor on the JFrame, *except* the window title bar that appears when the JFrame is decorated.

The code below will show a small JFrame with the cursor set to the Hand cursor.  However, it will not set the cursor to the hand cursor on the title bar.  In this part of the JFrame the cursor is set back to the system default.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ShowHandCursorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame aWindow = new JFrame();
        aWindow.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200);
        aWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        aWindow.getRootPane().setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        aWindow.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        aWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Is there some way to set the cursor to `Cursor.HAND_CURSOR` in the title bar as well?

Comment: The title bar of a JFrame window is handled by the Operating System. Conventional Java code can not change the mouse cursor over the Window title bar however there **may** be a JNI or JNA solution. You can however create a non-decorated JFrame and create your own Title Bar where your custom cursor will have an effect if it's really that important to you.

Comment: Thank you.  This explains why I could not find a pure java solution.